# Can someone tell me how to approach this Jenkins problem?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops

1. Repository: https://gitlab.com/arindam(only for example)
2. Create a Jenkinsfile that will deploy the application to remote EC2 server. Assume there is private ECR registry named "frontend_app" and credentials for aws are already configured. You just need to create a groovy script pipeline which will build, push image and deploy.
3. Create a bash script also which will install node using nvm and install version using user input.
4. Here are the build commands  for the deployment.

   - npm install
   - npm run build

Comment: Please tell us what you tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: how to share my script here its too long?

Comment: Normally, there's really much space for code here. (Please format it according to the possibilities shown on the right.) Anyway, it should not be neccessary to provide _all_ your code but a minimal reproducible example - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about that.